# Верстка изделия

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет! Уже писал, что давно не дружу с версткой,и стараюсь от неё отходить.
Так вот тут задача встала, для кого-то простая наверное.

Нужно сверстать такую картинку.

Каждое такое изделие должно быть **float:left** чтобы по остальному дизайну кол-во изделий на странице могло быть разным  + всё это изделие было кликабельным со ссылкой.
Значек скидки, понятное дело что только фон, саму скидку можно прописать руками, от 1% до 100, я думаю это должно быть понятно.
Ниже то что по глупости получилось у меня. Честно вааще нелюблю верстку, особенно большое кол-во элементов внутри одного. Кнопка "купить" появляется только при наведении на изделие, её не верстал даже.

Может кто что подскажет.

ps. конечно же чтобы под ослом 7-8 тоже как-то показывалось.

```
<div class="product"><a href="/catalog/product/pic">
                                    <div class="img" style="background: url(/img/cat/m/pic.jpg) -30px -20px; width:235px; height:185px;">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="discount"></div> // если скидки нет, то этот див не показываем и верстка не слетает
                                    <div class="price"><div class="pricetext">150р</div></div>
                                    <div class="orangemask">NEW</div>// тут так же как  и с дивом discount
                                    <div class="title">Серьга</div>
                                   </a>
                                </div>

.product{ // верхний див
    float:left;
    width: 235px;
    height: 195px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;

}

.product .img{
     border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    height: 185px;
    padding: -10px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

.product .title{
    color:#024b8e;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:140px 0 0 -90px;
}
.product a:link,a:hover{
     color:#8c8f8e;
     text-decoration: none;
}
.product .price{

    width:80px;
    height: 25px;
    margin:-207px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #b7b8b8;
    background:#8c8f8e url('/img/icons/rubwhite.png')58px 3px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 -10px 0;

}

.pricetext{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 4px 0 0 -18px;
    display:block; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pricetext:hover{text-decoration: none;}
.orangemask{
    background: #e94005;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:16px;
    width: 82px;
    height: 20px;
}
.product .price span{

    width:60px;
    margin: 0 0 -10px 0;

}
.product .discount{
    margin:-32px 0 0 180px;
    z-index: 100;
    width:57px;
    height:52px; 

}
```

[image]

Comment: Кто подскажет как просто расположить правильно элементы внутри дива? чтобы это не сказывалось на них при условии того что каких-то элементов не будет.

Comment: Если честно, то не очень понятно, что вы пытаетесь сказать. Не могли бы вы выложить то что у вас есть на http://jsfiddle.net/ 
Попробуйте назначить контейнеру position: relative а внутренним элементам position: absolute. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот держите верстку блока с изображением товара, на остальное пока нет времени, вечерком гляну, если будет время и никто не ответит. [надеюсь поможет](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/L9QFF/28/)

Comment: +10 в карму, щас гляну как на сайте смотреться будет.

Comment: @Shrek, как глянешь, отпишись. Поправлю если что...

Comment: [Пару маленьких корректировок](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/L9QFF/29/) для ответа @Alex83

Comment: 2 @deonis это я поправил сразу :)

Comment: @Deonis, скажите пожалуйста, чем такая запись лучше? :

     $('a.buy', this).fadeIn(500);

Это мне для общего развития...))

Comment: Это для именно этого тега a с классом buy? когда их на странице больше 1 то в твоем случае они все будут работать как один а в случае с this каждый сам за себя

Comment: Понял, спасибо. На сколько я понял, твоя проблема решена, или есть еще какие-то моменты?

Comment: решена, всем спасибо, все свободны :)

Реально верстка уже не моё :(